# RSpec deprecated behavior 'let'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am receiving these warnings when running my RSpec tests using Rspec-rails 2.14.  I want to upgrade to RSpec 3 to see if there are any performance improvements, but I assume these will all fail due to this warning?  I am using Factory girl also.

```
This is deprecated behavior that will not be supported in RSpec 3.

`let` and `subject` declarations are not intended to be called
in a `before(:all)` hook, as they exist to define state that
is reset between each example, while `before(:all)` exists to
define state that is shared across examples in an example group.
WARNING: let declaration `fa` accessed in a `before(:all)` hook at:
  D:/RailsApps/uwb/spec/models/fa_commercial_spec.rb:77:in `block (2 level
s) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is one example, how can this be changed so that it will be ok in RSpec 3?

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'FaCommercial' do
  let(:admin_user) {create(:user_admin_dev)}
  let(:template) {create :fa_commercial_template}
  let(:fa) {create :fa_commercial, fa_template: template}
  let(:stmt_template_bal_sheet) {create :fa_commercial_stmt_template_bal_sheet, fa_template: template}
  let(:stmt_template_cash_flow) {create :fa_commercial_stmt_template_cash_flow, fa_template: template}
  let(:stmt_template_income_stmt) {create :fa_commercial_stmt_template_income_stmt, fa_template: template}
  let(:stmt_template_ratios) {create :fa_commercial_stmt_template_ratios, fa_template: template}

  before(:all) do
    admin_user
    stmt_template_bal_sheet
    stmt_template_cash_flow
    stmt_template_income_stmt
    stmt_template_ratios
..........
```

Comment: It's saying not to reference `admin_user` etc. in a `before(:all)`. From what you've posted it's not clear why you are doing this rather than letting them be created lazily or calling them from a before(:each) (which would be equivalent to using let!)

Comment: sorry I'm new to all this, should I just move everything into the before(:all) block?  I have seen examples of let! too I'm not sure what these does, is it deprecated also?

Comment: `before(:all)` is evil. Don't use it to initialize models, use `before(:each)`. There are some good explanations with a simple google, you can also read this thread consider removing the feature at all: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/573

Comment: should I be using let? https://www.launchacademy.com/codecabulary/learn-test-driven-development/rspec/before-vs-let

Comment: Yes, you should be using `let`. Don't be scared off by naysayers :). Used appropriately, it helps DRY up your tests and makes them more readable.

Answer (score -1):

The error is self-explanatory.

```
`let` and `subject` declarations are not intended to be called
in a `before(:all)` hook
```

You might take a look at the RSpec documentation to understand how things works first, then, you will be able to refactor your scenarios in order to make it work.